# Cambiar Icono de color PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Hola a todos estoy tratando de realizar un cambio de color según el valor obtenido de la base de datos, debo de realizar la comparación de las ventas del día anterior y el día actual, ejemplo si el día anterior se obtuvo un total de $100.000 y el día actual va en $90.000 debe ponerse una flecha roja si en el transcurso del día se aumenta el $90.000 la flecha pasara hacer verde, mas o menos tengo una idea y ya logro hacerlo pero si le paso el numero quemado mas no se como aplicarlo para que sea dinámicamente, el codigo que tengo es el siguiente

Con este query traigo el numero de las ventas totales del día actual lo que lleva acumulado

```
$sqlayer = "SELECT fecha, sum(total) total FROM ventas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(fecha)=MONTH(NOW());";
$resultayer = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlayer);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultayer);
$total=$fila['total'];
```

Con este otro query obtengo las ventas del día anterior

```
<?php 
$sqlayer = "SELECT fecha, sum(total) total FROM ventas
WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(fecha) = DAY(NOW())-1";
$resultayer = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlayer);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultayer);
echo number_format( $fila['total'], 3, '.', '.');
?>
```

La idea que mas o menos tengo es la siguiente pero solo me compara las ventas del dia actual y me pinta la flecha bien solo que tiene que ser comparada con las ventas del dia anterior

```
<?php 
$sqlayer = "SELECT fecha, sum(total) total FROM ventas WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(fecha)=MONTH(NOW());";
  $resultayer = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlayer);
  $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultayer);
  $total=$fila['total'];
  $color=($total>340.444) ? '<span class="mr-2">
 <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up" style="color:#0AC627"></i></span>' : '
 <span class="mr-2">
 <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up" style="color:#EC1717;"></i></span>';
 echo $color;
 ?>
```

Si hay una forma mas adecuada de hacerlo se los agradeceria

Comment: Llevas 10 preguntas, y algunas con respuestas que parecen válidas, pero ninguna de ellas ha sido aceptada por ti.  Para que este sitio funcione bien y la comunidad sepa que respuestas son correctas a las preguntas realizadas, es importante aceptarlas cuando son válidas. Para aprender a aceptarlas mírate [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200), y para entender mejor el porque es importante mírate [este otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento del sitio, ya que lo usas es lo mínimo que deberias hacer.

Comment: Claro que si lo comenzare hacer desde ahora @masterguru

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente, no necesitas lanzar **dos consultas** para esto. Puedes sumar en una columna los totales de hoy, y en otra los totales de ayer y luego comparar.

La consulta sería esta:

```
$sql="
SELECT 
     SUM(
            CASE WHEN 
                DATE(fecha) = CURDATE() 
            THEN total ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS hoy,
       
     SUM(
            CASE WHEN 
                DATE(fecha) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
            THEN total ELSE 0 
            END
         ) AS ayer       
FROM ventas";
```

Luego obtienes los valores de las columnas `hoy` y `ayer` y comparas.

Por ejemplo:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hoy=$fila["hoy"];
$ayer=$fila["ayer"];
$color=($ayer > $hoy) ? "#0AC627" : "#EC1717";
$icon=($ayer > $hoy)  ? "fa-long-arrow-alt-up" : "fa-long-arrow-alt-down";

$span="<span class=\"mr-2\">
 <i class=\"fas $icon\" style=\"color:$color\"></i></span>";

echo $span;
```

- Más simple
- Más óptimo
- Más claro

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, como podria hacer que la flecha se muestre hacia abajo, obviamente se que tengo que buscar dicho icono

Comment: @Codej revisa la respuesta editada. He hecho lo mismo que hice con `$color`, creando una variable `$icon` donde será la flecha hacia arriba o hacia abajo según el caso y luego uso `$icon` dentro del `$span`.

Comment: Muchas gracias prefecto tal cual lo necesitaba